# What is the initial containing block and does it establish a block formatting context?

Tags: html, css, w3c

The standard [Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) says

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context
>
> ...

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yaway/Pz4QZ/

html

```
<div class="box-a bfc">drei</div>
<div class="box-b bfc">vier</div>
```

css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.box-a,
.box-b {
    height:100px;
    margin:10px 0;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.box-a {
    background-color:#fee
}
.box-b {
    background-color:#efe
}
.bfc {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The box "drei" and "vier" have collapsing margins

So I wonder if the initial containing block establishes a block formatting context(BFC),so these two boxes are in the same BFC.

But I failed to find that in W3C.

Comment: The previous question was completely different and it should not have been changed - the new question should have been posted as new, as done here. I've rolled back the edit and reopened this one as it wasn't exactly intended to be a repost.

Answer (score 0):

The [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) is defined as:

> The containing block in which the root element lives is a rectangle called the initial containing block.

i.e. It contains the `<html>` element for an HTML document.

It does establish a block formatting context, but the two elements in your example can't be children of it so there might be something else establishing a new block formatting context first.

I can't think of any circumstance where two `display: block`, `float: none`, `position: static` adjacent siblings won't share a block formatting context though.

Comment: Might it have something to do with normal flow? The root element is actually considered out-of-flow according to [section 9.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme). An out-of-flow element establishes flow for itself and all its in-flow contents while not being part of its parent flow (hence the term "flow root" in [css3-box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#types)). Since the root element doesn't have a parent, that makes sense. And since the root element is a flow root, it follows that it establishes a root block formatting context.

Comment: OK, css3-box says, "The terminology in the CSS level 2 specification is different. A flow root is called 'an element that establishes a new formatting context.'" which makes it a clarification on css3-box's part. So, I think that clears it up.